# how do I get the value of one of these buttons and change the class to active for the button clicked using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="hide-below-1200 btn-group" style="padding: 5px 0 5px 0;" data-toggle="buttons" role="group">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm active year-btn">All</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm year-btn">2017</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm year-btn">2016</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm year-btn">2015</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm year-btn">2014</button>
</div>
```

how do I get the value of one of these buttons and change the class to active for the button clicked using jQuery?

I tried this but i says the item is not defined

```
$(document).on("click", ".year-btn", function(e) {
        console.log($(this).children('button')[0].value);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, inside the handler `$(this)` is already a button, so `.children('button')` will result in `undefined`, second, when using jQuery, use `.val()` instead of `.value` but since what you want is the button's text, you must use `.text()`.

If you used `.val()` you would be getting the button's `value` attribute.

try this

```js
$(document).on("click", ".year-btn", function(e) {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        console.log("Text is " + $(this).text());
        console.log("Value is " + $(this).val());
    });
```

```css
button.active{
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hide-below-1200 btn-group" style="padding: 5px 0 5px 0;" data-toggle="buttons" role="group">
    <button value="val-All" class="btn btn-default btn-sm active year-btn">All</button>
    <button value="val-2017" class="btn btn-default btn-sm year-btn">2017</button>
    <button value="val-2016" class="btn btn-default btn-sm year-btn">2016</button>
    <button value="val-2015" class="btn btn-default btn-sm year-btn">2015</button>
    <button value="val-2014" class="btn btn-default btn-sm year-btn">2014</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to do that. and the **[Demo](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=3a8321eeba8f3d4f207c089f169d493e)** We get clicked element remove active class from all and add the clicked one only.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn').click(function(){
    $('.btn').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```